# Toggling className doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a toggle switch on JavaScript that changes the class of a div when another div is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
function toggleStart() {    
    var startToggle = document.getElementById('menustart').className;
    if (startToggle == "startmenu") {
        startToggle = 'startclick';
    } else {
        startToggle = 'startmenu';
    }
}
```

I basically want to add this function to the onclick property of a div. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This won't work because strings in JS are value type, not reference type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are struck with reassigning the class.

You are just changing the value of `startToggle` and not the value of element directly. For that you'll have to reassign the class name to the element for it take effect.

Add this line of code after `else` block:

```
document.getElementById('menustart').className = startToggle;
```

Comment: glad to have helped you ;)